# Update package.json in production

Tags: node.js, npm

If I edit my pagacke.json file on my production system after testing a specific package update, how would I install this specific update from my package.json file?

I could run npm update with this specific packages version. But how would I do this with the package.json file? For example if I edit the version of multiple packages manually?

Just running npm update would update all packages if updates are available, as far as I know.

So what I want is:
test updates locally -> update package.json file on production -> update those packages using edited package.json file

Comment: Editing the package file and re-running install is *not* a robust deployment mechanism. Ideally you don't directly edit production files at all, rather commits to version control are deployed (or built and deployed) by an automated, repeatable process. For repeatable dependency trees, prefer including both `package.json` *and* `package-lock.json` and running `npm ci` to install exactly the tree described in the lock file.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't meant to edit the the file in production directly. For sure I'd do this on a testing system. But after testing successfully commit the changes to the production build. So `npm ci` will install just the changed versions in the package.json / lock file?

Comment: `npm ci` deletes `node_modules/` and installs exactly what it says in `package-lock.json`. It errors if that can't be done, e.g. the specified versions can no longer be found or it doesn't match what the `package.json` says. See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ci.

Comment: All right, so it's rather a re-install with the specified versions in the files. But it suits the purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a project where:

- nothing has changed but one or more dependency entries in `package.json`
- you want the changes in `package.json` to be reflected in `node_modules`
- this is all happening on a production system

I'm not sure I would recommend such a process, but if you do find yourself in that situation, the answer is to run `npm install --production`. Anything in `node_modules` that meets the dependency requirements in `package.json` will be left alone. Only things that don't meet the requirements will be updated. The `--production` flag ignores devDependencies, which is presumably what you want in a production environment.

That answers your question. As for the process described, an incrementally better process might be to use the shrinkwrap feature in npm to generate an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file. That will at least insure that you get the exact same node_modules in your installations. (`package-lock.json` does a similar thing for development installations, and you can probably rely on that as well. But if you ever plan on publishing your project to a repository like npm's, the `package-lock.json` file is ignored. So you'll want `npm-shrinkwrap.json` in that case.)